# Is there a way to programmatically delete all local shared objects from within flash?

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript

I'm using local shared objects within flash both to store significant amounts of user data, as well as for caching data fetched from the server.

However, I'm very concerned about hitting the 100kb default limit.  Because the 100kb limit is for the whole domain, I'm concerned that the sum of multiple local shared objecs would sum to more than 100kb, but that each individual shared object would be less than 100kb.  In addition, I can't for the life of me find a way to list or clear all the local shared objects for a given domain.

Let's say you've created shared objects with random names, adding random data to each, such that you hit the 100kb limit.  Is there any way to delete these shared objects if you don't know the name of each object?  Or are you doomed to get the popup asking the user to increase the amount of storage space for shared objects?  If the latter is true, this seems like a major flaw in Flash's design of local shared objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whether it's a flaw or not is debatable, but at any rate I believe you're correct that there's no way to do this. It's made that way by design - by default, SharedObjects can only be deleted by the SWF that made them, or by SWFs within the specified "localPath" if one is specified. The feature is specifically designed so that one SWF from a given domain can't delete SharedObjects that belong to another SWF, unless you set it up that way.

After all, you wouldn't in general want an ad banner that happens to be served from `citibank.com/adbanners` to be able to access (in this case remove) SharedObjects from that site's loan simulators (or whatever).